# How can I populate DataGrid control with strings?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, binding, datagrid

I am trying to show up a list of strings in a datagrid, but I haven't been able to make it work correctly. The xaml is:

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="ListGrid" ItemsSource = "{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding trackTitle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

The Welcome.xaml.cs looks something like this, where trackTitle is a List

```
public Welcome()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListGrid.DataContext = MainWindow.trackTitle;
}
```

When I preview it, I can see the correct number of rows but no data for Title column. Also there is a column generated for Length and it shows the correct length for each string. What am I doing wrong? Is the Binding parameter for the Title column {Binding trackTitle} not right?

Comment: When you set the DataContext to `MainWindow.trackTitle`, `ItemsSource = "{Binding}"` will read that `trackTitle` value. Also, `Binding="{Binding trackTitle}"` will try to read `trackTitle.trackTitle`, which obviously fails. Look at your output window for binding errors.

Comment: Thank you! Removing trackTitle from Binding property worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example:

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**View Code-Behind**

```
namespace Example
{
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
namespace Example
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Entries { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Entry 1", "Entry 2", "Entry 3" };
            Entries = new ObservableCollection<string>(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Shows a good example of how to bind to a collection property in a ViewModel.  Try applying this to your situation.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for the MVVM example! I wanted to know whether the ViewModel part is in a different file or the same file as View file?

Comment: From what I've seen, the Views, ViewModels, and Models are all typically in separate files but I would still define it as personal preference. It will "work" without doing that but it's just kinda nice to keep everything broken up sometimes, especially when you a lot of Views, ViewModels, and Models.